# div z-index reverting to 'auto'

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I am using jQuery to append two divs which overlap to a container div (class='content'). I want to depth sort the two child divs:
The javascript:

```
$('.content').append('<div id="activePage"></div>');
    var pageContainer = $('#activePage');
    pageContainer.addClass("activePage").css('top', 136);
    pageContainer.append('<div id="pageBacking"></div>');
    $('#pageBacking').addClass("pageBacking");

    pageContainer.append('<div id="introLogo"></div>');
    $('#introLogo').append('<img src="file://<path to image here>/image.png" />');
    $('#introLogo').addClass("activePageContent");          
    console.log("backing z-index = "+$('#pageBacking').css("z-index"));
    console.log("intro logo z-index = "+$('#introLogo').css("z-index"));
    console.log("intro logo class = "+$('#introLogo').attr("class"));
```

the css:

```
.pageBacking {
    width: 736px;
    height: 562px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 30px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background: #01AEF0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.activePageContent {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

The console.logs say that the backing z-index is '1' and the intro logo z-index is 'auto'. The intro logo class is returned as 'activePageContent', so why isn't the introLogo div z-index 2? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsbin.com/uxoveb/1/edit unless I'm missing something..?

Comment: Because you haven't set the z-index for the intro logo and default z-index, auto has set?

Comment: I set the z-index for #introLogo by setting its class to activePageContent, so it should be 2.

Comment: position: absolute fixed it. In the jsbin you link to, you could only see the div with background. There was no image being pulled in to the other div to see if it was in front or behind. Just fyi...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you include the css for the container `.content` div?

Also, it looks like you never specify the `position: absolute;` for the `#introLogo` and as such it will ignore `z-index`.

To follow up, I recommend changing from:

```
.activePageContent {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

to:

```
.activePageContent {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: That's done the trick. Thanks! I didn't realise z-index needed absolute positioning.